# Hiding/Showing fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button, android-fragmentactivity

I have one `FragmentActivity` with `Buttons` in it and three `Fragment` classes. If Button 1 is clicked, I want to show `FragmentOne` and hide `FragmentTwo`,`FragmentThree`. and If `Button2` is clicked, I want to show `FragmentTwo` and hide `FragmentOne`,`FragmentThree` and vice versa. My code didn't work.

```
    private void fManager() {

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    f1 = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.first);
    f2 = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.second);
    f2 = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.third);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        if (b1.isPressed()) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.hide(f2);
            transaction.hide(f3);
            transaction.show(f1);
                            transaction.commit();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        if (b2.isPressed()) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.hide(f1);
            transaction.hide(f3);
            transaction.show(f2);
                            transaction.commit();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        if (b3.isPressed()) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.hide(f1);
            transaction.hide(f2);
            transaction.show(f3);
                         transaction.commit();
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to `commit` your transaction:

```
transaction.commit();
```

Also note that `show()` and `hide()` will work only for fragments added to the container (like i.e. `FrameLayout`) so if you got your fragments defined directly in XML then you may not be able to do that the way you try. Also if you use containers, just do regular `setVisibility()` on them instead of dealing with fragments there - the effect will be exactly the same.

Comment: manager or transaction? I have tried `transaction.commit();` it didn't work

Comment: Do check my code here http://pastebin.com/STkUKuSi and let me know  where to write setVisibility();

Answer (score 1):

It is just an typo error or you are using the same var name to reference two objects?

```
f2 = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.second);
f2 = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.third);
```

If you want to have some more info about trasaction give a look on my blog, [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-fragment-transaction.html).